# In swift, is there a way to have UIView class also be MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, mpmediapickercontroller

I am currently trying to make a music app using swift. This is my first app (not counting a couple tutorial things). I've been looking at some sample code, including Apple's addMusic example, and I have had issues with the following translation of the objective c code into swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate> {
```

I get the error "Cannot specialize non-generic type 'UIViewController'. Is there a way to do this that I am missing or will I need to define a separate class to be my picker delegate?

The addMusic code I was looking at is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AddMusic/Listings/Classes_MainViewController_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Classes_MainViewController_h-DontLinkElementID_5).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unlike in objective-c, the subclasses and delegates are structured the same as each other with none of the "<>" around them. For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, CustomClassDelegate
```

You can continually add to the list as you go along, though only one of them can be the superclass (the rest must be delegates or similar) as a class cannot be the subclass of two different parent classes at the same time.

Hope that helps.